# Get information from an array without loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to get term_id values from this array without any loops or foreach.
I need it To be:

First Term id is : 
Second Term id is :

I tried using echo $term[0]->term_id; but it is not working

Here is My var_dump result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Term)#4046 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(72)
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "samsung"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(91) "samsung"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(72)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "product_cat"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(63)
    ["count"]=>
    int(5)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(WP_Term)#4045 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(64)
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "onclikck"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(8) "onclikck"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(64)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "product_cat"
    ["description"]=>
    string(92) "Description"
    ["parent"]=>
    int(63)
    ["count"]=>
    int(3)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
}
```

Comment: what error you getting when you use it  ? $term[0]->term_id;

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$term[0]['term_id']
```